# How to ensure secure randomization for python password generator

Tags: python

Is there a way to have more secure randomization that is very hard to reproduce?

I have tried letting the user enter a seed to create more secure passwords so its harder to repeat the same seed, but i was wondering if there was a better/automatic way to do this?

```py
import random
import string

LENGTH = input("How long do you want your password?: ")
SEED = input("Seed? (The more random the better)")
GENLIST = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
if SEED != "":
    random.seed(SEED)

try:
    PASSWORD = ""
    for i in range(int(LENGTH)):
        PASSWORD += GENLIST[(random.randint(0, 61))]
    print()
    print(PASSWORD)
except TypeError:
    print("Integer not entered")
input()
```

Comment: use `random.SystemRandom()`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.urandom), which reads from the corresponding device.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) for random has has a section on this.

> Warning
>    
>   The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. Use os.urandom() or SystemRandom if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

I found this in a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22891583/8911039) question with some more discussion on the topic.