# Best practices for generating a random seeds to seed Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

What I really want is to seed the dataset and dataloader. I am adapting code from:

https://gist.github.com/kevinzakka/d33bf8d6c7f06a9d8c76d97a7879f5cb

Anyone know how to seed this properly? What are the best practices for seeding things in Pytorch.

Honestly, I have no idea if there is an algorithm specific way for GPU vs CPU. I care mostly about general pytorch and make sure my code is "truly random". Specially when it uses GPU I guess...

---

related:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-practices-for-seeding-random-numbers-on-gpu/18751
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-random-seed/19516/4
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-practices-for-generating-a-random-seed-to-seed-pytorch/52894/2

---

My answer was deleted and here is its content:

I don't know if this is the best for pytorch but this is what seems the best for any programming language:

---

Usually the best random sample you could get in any programming language is generated through the operating system. In Python, you can use the os module:

`random_data = os.urandom(4)`

In this way you get a cryptographic safe random byte sequence which you may convert in a numeric data type for using as a seed.

`seed = int.from_bytes(random_data, byteorder="big")`

EDIT: the snippets of code works only on Python 3

---

'''
Greater than 4 I get this error:

ValueError: Seed must be between 0 and 2**32 - 1
'''

RAND_SIZE = 4

Comment: Could you please tell us how the [official doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) (they have a page specifically for this) is not clear about that? I can suggest a PR to make it clearer, but I don't see any problem right now.

Comment: @Berriel seems from the answer I posted what I was trying to do is get a "real" random number. Not about reproducibility but I find I wanted something else I will update/let you know.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

This is what I use

```
def seed_everything(seed=42):
  random.seed(seed)
  os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
  np.random.seed(seed)
  torch.manual_seed(seed)
  torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
  torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

the two last parameters (cudnn) are for GPU

and you can generate a seed as follow:

```
def get_truly_random_seed_through_os():
    """
    Usually the best random sample you could get in any programming language is generated through the operating system. 
    In Python, you can use the os module.

    source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416925/best-practices-for-generating-a-random-seeds-to-seed-pytorch/57416967#57416967
    """
    RAND_SIZE = 4
    random_data = os.urandom(
        RAND_SIZE
    )  # Return a string of size random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.
    random_seed = int.from_bytes(random_data, byteorder="big")
    return random_seed
```

Comment: what is ur `seed=42` do? is that when we want it to behave deterministically?

Comment: Note, what I actually want is to provide the seed as optional input and then thats when its deterministic but when its not give, to behave randomly and have the os choose it...or at least thats what I have now.

Comment: yeah seed is used as the seed for your results to be reproducable with different runs. you can change it to have different semi-random numbers generated.

Comment: you can have seed=None as default parameter and have an if to only execute the code block if seed is not None

Comment: wait you aren't generating a seed...which the title requires