# True random number generator in python or javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, random

I am trying to implement a simple pseudo random generator used in cryptography called LFSR (linear feedback shift register).

I have checked a few JS and Python websites for a way to generate a True Random Number but all I find is pseudo random number generator.

Is it possible to get a TRN from these coding languages ?

Just some pointers would be fine, I am not originally a coder so got a bit confused by this.

Comment: There is [cryptographic safe randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate true random numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746362/generate-true-random-numbers-in-python)

Comment: See also my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746362/generate-true-random-numbers-in-python/63746585#63746585

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in JS as well.

Answer (score 2):

True randomness comes from stuff like detecting radioactive decay events. So no, you cannot achieve true randomness with standard hardware.

Comment: I dont think anyone can predict the electronic-circuit state of a laptop, so I wonder if fluctuations in the current or the circuit could be used.

Comment: Could intel [intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214457/how-to-use-rdrand-intrinsics) be of any use to you?

Comment: Python [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

On your own, achieving true randomness is very difficult, but some APIs that do this exist.

`random.org` does it, for example.

Comment: Thanks but why? Please see comment to the prev answer.

Comment: There are plenty of accessible chaotic events that could be harnessed in order to generate a random seed (wind, environmental sounds, maybe the electronic-circuit state you talked about...?), but the difficulty resides in using them in a meaningful way without appropriate sensing equipment and without being able to influence the results by provoking those kinds of events near the sensors.

Comment: @QuentinPortet Having a random seed doesn't make a PRNG "truly random". The seed just sets the initial state of a PRNG. Given enough observations, the state can be inferred and subsequent values can be predicted with certainty.

Comment: @pjs I hadn't thought of that! It makes sense, thank you!