# Real random python numbers

Tags: python, random

i need to create random numbers in python, i have been using the `random` library, but is this library really random or is it just pseudo random?  and if it is pseudo random how can I get real random numbers in python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891583/can-i-generate-authentic-random-number-with-python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I generate authentic random number with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891583/can-i-generate-authentic-random-number-with-python)

Answer (score 3):

All computer generated random numbers are pseudo-random.  If you want a more "randomized" version, you can use the secrets module instead of the random module.